# Git rebase applying dos2unix at each step

Tags: git, dos2unix

I've a series of commits to a file that I now realize was created with incorrect line endings.  I want to rebase the commits and apply `dos2unix` command at each step.  I can't see an easy way to do this as after each step git registers a full conflict with the file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter-branch`.

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'dos2unix filename' master
```

(Assuming the commits you want to modify are on `master`. You can also use a more specific list of commit names, instead of applying the filter to the entire branch.)

Comment: Hmmm, doesn't seem to work.
As there are 10K+ commits I'm executing it as follows: `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'dos2unix filename' commit-before-file-was-first-added..master`
It runs through all those commits, but then says
`WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged`
at the end, (and `filename` has been changed to unix format, but in the working directly only).

Comment: You might need to checkout another branch first, so that the branch head can be updated.

Comment: Hm, I think `filter-branch` is the way to go here, but I do not know the command well enough to debug the issue or to advise further. Maybe someone else can provide a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer though! I experimented with the `rm -f` command (example from docs) instead of `dos2unix` and got the same result (no change to commit history but file removed at the end)

Answer (score 0):

which environment was used to modify the file with incorrect line endings ? if it's windows make sure your workspace is using UTF-8 encoding.

You can manage that through git config (see link for option) :

```
git config core.autocrlf true
```

if set to true this converts LF endings into CRLF when you check out code (when working under windows)

More infos :
http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I was asking - the file was not originally committed by me (and was originally committed via svn anyway).

Comment: It seems that EoghanM's problem is that the actual git objects in the repo already have the Windows line endings.